# Lasso logistic cross validated error

Tags: regression, logistic, lasso, glmnet

I fitted a lasso logistic regression using glmnet. I use a pretty small dataset with only 51 (28/23) observations. I want to compare the model fit of two possible variable combinations.

1. Only control variables
2. Control variables + linguistic predictors

Both models are comparable regarding explained deviance with best lambdas (1.:17% | 2.:16% dev. explained from null model).

Now I want also compare the mean cross validated error at the best lambdas. Again both models are pretty close (1.: 1.304177 | 2.: 1.324639).

My questions are:

1.) What exactly measures this score? Is it RMSE as measured in linear regression?

2.) From a predictive perspective: Is such a score either good or bad? (I would guess it is not the best predicitve model on earth)

3.) What would a good score look like?

Comment: 1) is answered by looking at the documentation `?cv.glmnet`. Scroll down to `type.measure`.

Comment: Thx @GeneralAbrial, so it measures deviance too, because i use the default optimization parameter, which is deviance.

Comment: @GeneralAbrial, do you know how exactly cv.glmnet calculates the cvm scores when option "deviance" is chosen? Is it "deviance score"? I want to report some kind of error statistic from CV to show the expected predictive potential of my models.

Comment: This is covered in the documentation. `cvm` is the out-of-sample mean of whatever metric you have chosen.

Answer (score -1):

1) For logistic regression use type.measure="class" or "auc" depending on whether it is a binomial or a multinomial classification.

2) Plot the two models using a ROC curve (use ROCR package) and compare the area under the curve as shown below.

[image]

3) A good score would depend on the baseline you are comparing with. If your baseline is random guessing you are comparing against the purple line.

Comment: At best this is incomplete. Re: (1) Read `type.measure` in `?cv.glmnet`. For logistic regression, default is `deviance`, but also has options `class`, `auc`, `mae` and `mse`. Perhaps you are making a recommendation to only use `class` or `auc` for logistic regression? In either case, using accuracy is an improper scoring rule, so it will select the wrong model with high probability. Re (2) models may be profitably be compared on the basis of deviance, Brier score and so on. OP is not constrained to solely compare models on the basis of AUC.

Comment: You don't need to waste space on ROC curves, as the AUC (concordance probability; $c$-index) has meaning (and better interpretation) without it.  And auc may not be the best index anyway.  Consider Brier score and deviance-based measures.  More importantly the sample size is far too small for `lasso` to work reliably.  Try bootstrapping the whole process and checking for volatility of features selected.